# Is it possible to query through a compressed file using AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

We are uploading our database to AWS S3. Recently, we decided to upload our database in a compressed format (zip), and when needed, use a python application to unzip it and query through the db with AWS Athena.

Is there any compression format that Athena can read without needing to decompress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Compression Formats - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/compression-formats.html):

> Athena supports the following compression formats:
>
> - SNAPPY (Default compression format for files in the Parquet format)
> - ZLIB. (Default compression format for files in the ORC format)
> - GZIP
> - LZO